# How reload only one item from a cell in a collectionView? Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have a collectionView with one cell and 3 items like this
[collectionView with 3 items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSnCA.png) 
[image]

I need to refresh only one item every second, in this case the "Label 2" 
 needs to change every second, but when I make collectionView.reloadData() the UIImage and all the cell blinks a little and occasionally changes the image

Comment: just to be sure, you have only one cell in your collection view and this cell contains the three elements: image, label 1, label 2? So reloading the collection view or the cell will always fully reload your only cell.

Comment: Exact, the image, label 1 and label 2 are in only one cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
collectionView.reloadItems(at: indexPaths)
```

Call this method to selectively reload only the specified items. This causes the collection view to discard any cells associated with those items and redisplay them.

Comment: Using `reloadItems(at:)` is part of the correct answer, but the code you posted submits an empty array of indexPaths, and therefore doesn't make sense. Better to say `let indexPaths = [indexPathToChange]`, and add a comment that the OP should provide the IndexPath that they want to update. Or at the very least, add a comment that the OP would need to add a line of code to append the desired IndexPaths to the array before calling `reloadItems(at:)`

Comment: yes I make an Array of index but always reload the image and that broke my collection view

Answer (score 3):

Call `reloadItems(at:)` and pass in an array containing a single IndexPath of the cell you want to reload.

The Xcode docs on `UICollectionView` are quite good. You should read them.